# File handling in c#

Tags: c#

In my c# application, when i upload a file , it needs to be converted to temp file and store in a temporary folder then read the temp file as image find its height width  every thing and later stores in databse.I am getting error when I read the temp file as image, as Out of Memory, below is my entire code.

```
string img = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath +@"\"+ path;
//in path .png file is accessed.
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(img);
            string internetCache = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
            string IEPath=internetCache+@"\tmp";
            if (!Directory.Exists(IEPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(IEPath);


            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(img);
            FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
            //lResult = URLDownloadToFile(0, img.src, TempFolder & strFileName, 0, 0)
            Stream stream = fs;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            stream.Seek(273, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);

            string tempfile = Path.Combine(IEPath, Math.Abs(filename.GetHashCode()) + ".tmp");
            File.WriteAllBytes(tempfile, buffer);
            fs.Close();
            stream.Close();

            string _contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            FileType Type = FileType.png;
            string MimeType = "image/png";
            FileStream fst = new FileStream(tempfile, FileMode.Open);
            Image _image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fst, true, true);
```

The last line where I am getting the exception as out of memory.
Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Why are you skipping the first 273 bytes?

Comment: Have you tried saving the file and then opening that saved file to make sure the data is correct?

Comment: 273 i just given for testing.I didnt try to open the file.

Comment: Its not my intention not to accept the answers, i just dont know hoe to accept them.

Comment: There are two serious mistakes in this code.  Dumping files in the IE cache directory will make it run out of disk space eventually.  Not understanding GetHashCode() will make it fail randomly, but not frequently, with a Generic GDI+ error.  But the real bug is not in the snippet, you are no doubt forgetting to call Dispose() on the created _image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed the instructions of the question:

1. read some file
2. Copy the file to a temp file
3. Read as image
4. Get width & height

   ```
   var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\duck.jpg");
   var temp = Path.GetTempFileName();
   File.WriteAllBytes(temp, bytes);

   var img = Image.FromFile(temp);
   Console.WriteLine ("width: {0}, height: {0}", img.Width, img.Height);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I'd venture that the stream you are reading is corrupted (perhaps because you remove the leading 273 bytes).